# Include controller and model source code of Razor Class Library

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

Is it possible to view and include the source code for the controller and models of the Identity package in Asp.Net Core 3 into my VS project?

I have scaffolded the package but it currently shows only the view files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no controller or model code. The Identity default UI uses Razor Pages. With Razor Pages, there's a code-behind (.cshtml.cs), which has methods similar to controller actions, called handlers, and the model is actually a `PageModel` and is the entire backing class for the view.

The views should have a little arrow to the left of them, which you can expand to show the code-behind.